# Determine cluster of access time within 10min intervals per user per day in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to query in SQL from the sample data, it will group or cluster the access_time per user per day within 10min intervals?

[image: Sample Data]

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: Nope, I've no idea how to go from your sample data to the expected result. Can you explain, for instance, why we end up with two rows in the result at 18:22 with different `cluster` values? We don't charge by the word here, add more explanation into your question

Comment: And now you've added [tag:sql-query-store] to your question and it's not at *all* clear why.

Comment: Along with an explanation, take the time to post your data in a consumable format as well. DDL and DML statements are best, however, (well formatted) tabular formatted `text` is still acceptable. Images, however, don't help us help you, as we can't use your data.

Comment: I wanted to show all access time within 10min intervals, so possible that date and user_id may reflect 2 or more times but cluster numbering must be the same if the clustered time ex: 9/19/20 18:15    9/19/20 18:22 their interval is just 7mins.

Comment: Why are so many of the rows not in your expected results? What eliminates them?

Answer (score 0):

This is a *complete* guess, based on reading between the lines, and is **untested** due to a lack of consumable sample data.

It, however, *looks* like you are after a triangular `JOIN` (these can perform poorly, especially as this won't be SARGable) and a `DENSE_RANK`:

```sql
SELECT YT.[date],
       YT.User_ID,
       YT2.AccessTime,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY YT.[date], YT.User_ID ORDER BY YT1.AccessTime) AS Cluster
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN dbo.YourTable YT2 ON YT.[date] = YT2.[date]
                           AND YT.User_ID = YT2.User_ID
                           AND YT.AccessTime <= YT2.AccessTime                    --This will join the row to itself
                           AND DATEADD(MINUTE,10,YT.AccessTime) >= YT2.AccessTime; --That is intentional
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem you want to group all accesses for a user in a day when all accesses of that group are in a time interval of 10 minutes. Not counting single accesses, so an access distant more than 10 minutes from every other is not counted as a cluster.

You can identify the clusters joining the accesses table with itself to get all possible time intervals of 10 minutes and number them.

Finally simply rejoin access table to get accesses for each cluster:

```
; with
user_clusters as (
    select a1.date, a1.user_id, a1.access_time cluster_start, a2.access_time cluster_end,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by a1.date, a1.user_id order by a1.access_time) user_cluster_id
    from ACCESS_TIMES a1
    join ACCESS_TIMES a2 on a1.date = a2.date and a1.user_id = a2.user_id 
    and a1.access_time < a2.access_time
    and datediff(minute, a1.access_time, a2.access_time)<10
)
select * 
from user_clusters c
join ACCESS_TIMES a on a.date = c.date and a.user_id = c.user_id and a.access_time between c.cluster_start and cluster_end
order by a.date, a.user_id, c.user_cluster_id, a.access_time
```

output:

```
date            user_id     access_time             user_cluster_id
'2020-09-19',   'AA083P',   '2020-09-19 18:15:00',  1
'2020-09-19',   'AA083P',   '2020-09-19 18:22:00',  1
'2020-09-19',   'AA083P',   '2020-09-19 18:22:00',  2
'2020-09-19',   'AA083P',   '2020-09-19 18:28:00',  2
'2020-09-20',   'AB162Y',   '2020-09-20 19:34:00',  1
'2020-09-20',   'AB162Y',   '2020-09-20 19:37:00',  1
```